# Establish PPPD connection using linux to communicate with modem

Tags: linux, modem, gprs, pppd

When PPP is trying to establish communication with module i get this message on log file:

```
Serial connection established.
using channel 6
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyO5
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Receive serial link is not 8-bit clean:
Problem: all had bit 7 set to 0
Modem hangup
```

It seems the module does not responds to LCP requests and i don't understand why.

my /etc/ppp/options file is:

```
lock
crtscts
defaultroute
noauth
hide-password
noipdefault
default-asyncmap
```

My chat file is:

```
ABORT "BUSY"
ABORT "NO CARRIER"
ABORT "Username/Password Incorrect"
SAY "Starting chat file \n"
'' AT
SAY "\n ATE0"
OK ATE0
SAY "\n AT#SELINT=2"
OK AT#SELINT=2
SAY "\n AT+IPR=57600"
OK AT+IPR=57600
SAY "\n AT&K3"
OK AT&K3
SAY "\n AT+CMEE=2"
OK AT+CMEE=2
SAY "\n AT+CPIN=6512"
OK AT+CPIN=6512
SAY "\n Logging in...."
OK AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.vodafone.pt","0.0.0.0",0,0
OK AT#USERID="vodafone"
OK AT#PASSW="vodafone"
SAY "\n AT#GPRS=1"
OK AT#GPRS=1`
```

The SAY string is only for trace on log.

Comment: Hi, have you tried connecting manually via AT commands and something like wvdial or Hypperterminal, and does that work?

Comment: Yes it works, actually i discovered an error on my chat file and now it is working partially. Now when PPP is trying to set a connection with module i get this output on log file: Serial connection established.
using channel 6
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyO5
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc83c6fe3>]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Receive serial link is not 8-bit clean:
Problem: all had bit 7 set to 0

Comment: The comments are a bit hard to read, so update the question with this information, if you're still looking for help.